# Cron job for docker compose

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, cron

I have a scraping script which stores the data in SQLite and needs to be run in every 20 minutes. I set the script on EC2 and when I do `docker-compose up` it works as intended, but when I set it to be run by cron job, it seems like the db is not update and the logic is not executed.

Here is the `Dockerfile`:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:3.9-slim-buster
ADD . /source
WORKDIR /source
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python3 -m pip install requests-html
CMD ["python3", "-m", "source.create_db.db_management"]
```

Here is the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
      build: .
      volumes:
          - .:/source
```

and here is the cron job:

```
*/20 *  *   *   *    /home/ubuntu/order_migrator/docker-compose up
```

Comment: Well, it you had already run `docker-compose up`, what do you expect the cron job to do?

Comment: to run `source.create_db.db_management` every 20 minutes.